# Migrate from log4j1 to log4j2 using Log4j Bridge

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I am starting to migrate an existing project from log4j1 to log4j2, i added the following maven dependencies

```
     <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>

    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>

    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
```

I also deleted all logj1 jar like they say on the offical migration guide, i don't know if i have to replace all log4j.xml configuration files with log4j2.xml and change the configuration to the new syntax?
If it's the case, how i can do with third parties that use log4j and configure it with log4j.xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there can only be a single logging configuration per application. If a third party is providing a logging configuration in a jar to be included in your app that is an issue. If it is a separate third party app then I don't understand why you are porting it from Log4j 1 to Log4j 2. That should be their problem.

Yes, your dependencies are correct. As for whether to use a log4j 1 format configuration or log4j 2 I would always recommend using the log4j 2 format if you can do the work. You can certainly try to use the log4j 1 configurations by following http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/compatibility.html.

Comment: yes i have a third party, which include a log4j.xml in the jar, would that be a problem after using the log4j bridge?

Comment: Not if you only use Log4J 2 configurations.

Comment: i just tried using log4j.xml config file after setting "log4j1.compatibility" property i got a ClassNotFoundException on  org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender, i don' know why but RollingFileAppender is included on Supported this experimental feature. (im on version 2.13.3)

Comment: Try adding setting the log4j2.debug system property and see if you get some diagnostics.

Comment: apparently it's due to <param name="file"> on my log4j.xml file, i look at the code base and while parsing it check for "File" otherwise we don't set filename ...